# How to get exact number of follows in New Pages Experience

Tags: facebook

I manage a page and switched to the New Pages Experience, which [removed the number of likes](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/2683010948601738?id=418112142508425), no longer shows the number of followers on the public page, and shows the number of follows when I'm signed in as `1.1k`.

Is it possible to get the exact number of follows in the New Pages Experience?